# Гибкая картинка

Tags: ios, swift

Ребят не подскажите, как сделать картинку "гибкой"? Чтобы если iPhone 11 Pro Max (то картинка увеличивается в зависимости от размера), а если это iPhone SE, то картинка автоматически уменьшается? Подскажите как это сделать или какой "функционал" у картинки выбрать.

Answer (score 2):

Видимо вы имеете в виду масштабирование, при использовании `UIImageView` вы можете устанавливать с помощью свойства `contentMode` режим масштабирования изображения в зависимости от цели:

```
.scaleToFill

.scaleAspectFit

.scaleAspectFill
```

Подробнее о различиях этих режимов можно почитать например [здесь](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/stretching-redrawing-and-positioning-with-contentmode)

Answer (score 0):

Крепите ваш `UIImage` на экране и ставите свойство `.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill` .
В основном ставят так. Но как выше писали, вы можете попробовать разные значения.